# list indices must be int, not str. But I want them to be str

Tags: python, list, indices

```
def main():
    score = 0
    answers = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
    testA = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
    for line in testA:
        gr = str(line)
        if gr == str(answers[line]):
            score+=1
    testA.close()
    checkpass(score)

def checkpass(score):
        if score >= 15:
            print("You passed")
        else:
            print("You failed")
main()
```

I'm trying to write some ^ code which takes a text file and compares its entries to the list recorded above. If the letter in the text file is the same as that of the list at simultaneous indexes, the accumulator should add one. Why can't I check if A == A or B==B in a list? Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `if gr == str(answers[line]):` ? you probably want: `if line in answers:`

Comment: I think you're saying that if the first line of the file is `B`, then you want to score a point. If the second line is `D`, then score a point. And in general, if the n'th line of the file is the n'th entry in `answers`, then score a point. From that spec, you can start writing code.

Comment: I wanted to check if gr is equal to the string character in the list 'answers' at index #line..

Comment: yes Raymond that's what I want to do, but I expected the code that I wrote to fulfill that task. Could you show what a better approach would be?

Answer (score 3):

When you iterate over a file with `for line in testA:`, the `line` variable gets a *string* containing one line from the file.

But, you're trying to use this string as an index into your `answers` list (`answers[line]`).  If each line is supposed to match up with the answers sequentially, you need to index one-by-one into the `answers` list. This means you want to use the *line **number*** as an index:  `answers[line_number]`.

Luckily, this is simple to do in Python, with [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for line_number,line_contents in enumerate(testA):
    gr = str(line_contents )
    if gr == str(answers[line_number]):
```

When iterating over something, `enumerate` will give you the *index* and the *item*, for every item in the iterable.

---

Note that `line_contents` is already a string, so there's no point in the `str()` cast. Also, since you're comparing each against a single character, you probably want to eliminate any whitespace from the input file as well. We can do that with a call to `str.strip()`:

```
for line_number,line_contents in enumerate(testA):
    gr = line_contents.strip()
    if gr == str(answers[line_number]):
```

---

When working with files, it's best to use them in a `with` block. This makes sure that the file is automatically closed, even if something goes wrong  during execution:

```
with open('newfile.txt', 'r') as testA:
    for line_number,line_contents in enumerate(testA):
        gr = line_contents.strip()
        if gr == str(answers[line_number]):
            score += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the problematic part

```
    for line in testA:
        gr = str(line)
        if gr == str(answers[line]):
            score+=1
```

`line` is a `str` type, unlike Javascript which you may be accustomed to, `for` construct in python returns the *value*, not the *key*.  So you could use `enumerate` which will provide a handy index which you can reference the answer like the other answer.  However, there is a better construct for this which is [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip), which will let you do this:

```
    for answer, line in zip(answers, testA):
        if answer == line.strip():  # strip off the trailing newline
            score += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining `zip` and `sum` simplifies this function a lot

```
def main():
    answers = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
    with open('newfile.txt', 'r') as testA:
        score = sum(i.strip() == j for i, j in zip(testA, answer))
    checkpass(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on the language you're using, but for most programming languages lists are indexed starting from 0. Meaning that you would have to check the 0th entry of the array against the value you want.

In most languages, such as c++, the syntax is fairly easy to use (you might have to convert for the language you're using.

C++ syntax for checking against a value:
    // Ignore the 'char' part if you want, that's not part of Python (I believe).
    char someArray[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' ... }; // Create the list, add a random number of elements

```
if (someArray[0] == 'a) // This checks to make sure the 0th entry is 'a' before continuing
{
    ... Do something ...
}
```

Basically the index is telling you where you want to evaluate within the array, so it requires an integer to do so. If you want to pass a string to it, it won't have any clue what you're talking about.

EDIT: I see by the tag it is in Python, but the general meaning I conveyed should still hold mostly.

Comment: could I not then just use [line + 1] instead of [line], seeing as the first line of the text file will be processed as the first line?

Comment: I believe that 'line' in this case is referring to the value stored in the line, and not the line-number itself. You could use another variable that would be an integer and do a int++ operation each time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the length of answers and the lines in testA are equal you add a counter for an indexer like so:

```
def main():
    score = 0
    answers = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
    testA = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
    counter = 0 #initialize counter
    for line in testA:
        gr = str(line)
        if gr == answers[counter]:
            score+=1
        counter += 1 #increment counter
    testA.close()
    checkpass(score)

def checkpass(score):
        if score >= 15:
            print("You passed")
        else:
            print("You failed")
main()
```

Comment: Don't use `*` to highlight sections of code!  Add a `#comment` instead, or something that leaves for valid syntax!

Comment: and as other poster said, it needs `gr = str(line).strip()`.. so if @user3366963 doesn't want to use `enumerate` or `zip`, you may also use this `counter`..